# Programming for/modding bitcoin-qt on Windows

Tags: bitcoin-core, development, windows

In multiple places I've found methods of modifying or adding to the bitcoin-qt(or other coin wallet) source on ubuntu or osx, but how would I do this on a Windows machine? If possible, I'd like to be able to use an IDE(pretty much required) to be able to build, but also, I need some way to edit. Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt is a multiplattform library, so is its IDE (qtcreator). You can compile bitcoin-qt on Windows pretty much the same that yo do on Linux.